# Holding a PBS Job in a For-Loop of Bash Script

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, jobs, pbs

```
#!/bin/bash

totT=0

for a in `seq -w 3.5 0.1 4.5`
do 
echo "a= $a"

cat >POSCAR <<!
Al FCC
1.0
$a 0.00 0.00
0.00 $a 0.00
0.00 0.00 $a
4
Direct
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.5 0.0 0.5
0.5 0.5 0.0
0.0 0.5 0.5
!

###I want to write a command to submit vasp.sh to PBS queue within the loop. How can I do it?
qsub vasp.sh
qsub -sync y vasp.sh
###

V=`grep volume/ion OUTCAR | awk '{print $5/4}'`
E=`tail -n1 OSZICAR | awk '{print $5/4}'`
totT=`echo $totT $T|awk '{print $1+$2}'`

echo $a $E >> EvsA
echo $V $E >> EvsV

./cleanup.sh

done
```

Hi I am trying to write a Bash script that loops over another script called vasp.sh, which takes in POSCAR as an input, and produces OUTCAR and OSZICAR as outputs. But I want vasp.sh in each iteration to finish execution before the start of the next iteration, as I want to do something with the output files before deleting them with cleanup.sh in each iteration. I tried **qsub -sync y vasp.sh** to wait for the job to complete before the next iteration, but the terminal says 's', 'y', 'n' are invalid options. Can someone teach me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how did decided to pass "-sync' option to qsub. qsub's man page does not mention these options at all.

There are two ways I can think of doing what you want to do.

1 - You can submit a job and make qsub block unless the job is done. "qsub -Wblock=True vash.sh" should do it. I wouldn't recommend this option because depending on the workload in your complex, you can never guess when the job will be over.

2 - I recommend using job dependency to submit your jobs. Once you submit the first job, capture its job-id and submit subsequent jobs as - "qsub -Wdepend=after: vasp.sh". Doing this will ensure that your workflow is followed and jobs run one after another.